# Perceptron in R

Tags: r

I'm very new to this site. I have a query regarding the perceptron algorithm, where the question is 'implement the perceptron' in R. So below is what I did with two (very easy) data points. But there is something missing and I can't figure out what. Can someone help?

```
z=c(1,2)
zz=c(-1,-2)
plot(z,zz)
zzz=c(2,3,4,-1)
z4=c(1,2,2,-1)
plot(zzz,z4)
p=function(zzz,z4,learning.rate=0.1,converge){
 w=c(rep(0,3))
  converged = FALSE
  while(converged==FALSE){
    converged = TRUE
    for(i in 1:length(z4)){
      if (zzz[i]%*%t(z4[i]) <= 0){
        t(w[i])= t(w[i])+learning.rate%*%t(x[i])
      }
    }
    converged = FALSE
  }  
}
```

Comment: What is the unwanted outcome that occurs?

Comment: It seems that your `while` will never stop as `converged` is always `FALSE`.

Comment: You're right Paul, my 'while' never stops and it keeps looping. I now corrected that and also corrected the x[i] as this is a mistake. A friend of mine told me that I should assign 'labels' to my dataset. So now I am trying to figure out how to do that.